# How to position element at the bottom of a screen using RelativeLayout's constraints?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to position element at the bottom of a screen using RelativeLayout's constraints? Currently, I'm using this code:

```
<Image x:Name="img" Opacity="1"
                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"/>
```

To set a picture as a background, however I need it to start from the bottom, therefore, I need to position it at the bottom. How should I do that? I haven't found any examples of that in the internet. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the RelativeView as your container. 
The make it FillAndExpand in both Horizontal Options and Vertical Options. 
So now your screen size is the size of your relative layout.

Now you have an image starting at the left bottom and full width :

```
<Image x:Name="img" Opacity="1"
                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.25}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.75}"/>
```

Also you can set the Aspect, if your image is of smaller size than the screen.

> Aspect - How to size the image within the bounds it is being displayed
>   within (whether to stretch, crop or letterbox).

The Aspect determines how the image will be scaled to fit the display area:

- Fill - Stretches the image to completely and exactly fill the display area. This may result in the image being distorted.
- AspectFill - Clips the image so that it fills the display area while preserving the aspect (ie. no distortion).
- AspectFit - Letterboxes the image (if required) so that the entire
  image fits into the display area, with blank space added to the
  top/bottom or sides depending on the whether the image is wide or
  tall.

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze - use aspect ratio.

Comment: I'll try, but isn't the width constraint supposed to deal with the problem?

Comment: No, Please read through the documentation of Aspect. Width constraint sets the layout bounds

Comment: I'm not asking abouy the Aspect. I'm asking, isn't setting width constraint to  the width of the parent, supposed to stretch the view to fit the parent?

Comment: It will stretch the bounds but you need specify what you need to do with the loaded image inside. You try by setting different background color to parent and child layout

Comment: You seem to know what are you talking about! I'll try your solution and will accept uour answer soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the X-Position (and/or Y-Position) of your Image, relative to your parent (just like the with or height). I used following code to place a button (with width and height of 60) at the bottom-right of the Screen:

```
<ContentView RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                      Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Constant=-70}"
             RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                      Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Constant=-70}">
    <Button />
</ContentView>
```

You can find more details in the [Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/#Understanding_Constraints).

Comment: Yeah but i want it to be able to adapt to different screen sizes. Will that be possible?

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood you.. but with the constraints of the relativelayout, you refer to the width and height of the element (not depending on the screen size). So, this should work (at least in my head). Otherwise, update your question to clarify what you want.